# Exclude constant substring while searching for different substring remaining original indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I'd like to find (original) index of substring e.g. `"cac"` while ignoring some other (constant) substring e.g. `"<ee>"`.

```
import re

string = "aaac<ee>acbbb"
pattern=re.compile("<ee>") # pattern to exclude
re.search("cac", pattern.sub("",string))
```

I've tried using regex, but this gives me only the index of newly established string (pattern excluding):

```
<re.Match object; span=(3, 6), match='cac'>
```

Is there any way to get first and last index of `"cac"` regardless to inserted charcters/strings etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the part to "ignore" in your pattern:

```
re.search("c(<ee>)*a(<ee>)*c",string)
```

which, for your `string`, produces

```
<re.Match object; span=(3, 10), match='c<ee>ac'>
```